# Clustering: how to bias clustering by making some values more/less relevant?

Tags: r, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I'm using hierarchical clustering in R to generate groups from certain data. I would like to do something to influence the algorithm so it takes into account some values as "more relevant" or, on the contrary, some other values are considered as "to be clustered far away".

In my example, individuals with certain characteristics (dimensions), some of them have zero values for certain dimensions. According to my model, these individuals must be pushed away from the ones that have some values (either the values are low or high). For example:

```
          Number of Children      Bank savings     
Joe               3                   1000$
Martha            0                   1000$
Pete              1                   5000$
```

I'd like the algorithm to give relevance to the fact "have any children", so Martha must be in a group different from Joe and Pete, that (at least) have 1 children or more. I tried this by replacing zero values by a negative value, for example the negative mean of the values in that column, which in this example is -2. Therefore the input matrix could be like this:

```
          Number of Children      Bank savings     
Joe               3                   1000$
Martha           -2                   1000$
Pete              1                   5000$
```

However, the results are not satisfactory.

On the other hand, I'd like to do something as the opposite of the example above, that is, do that some dimensions have certain affinity between them. Let's say we have three dimensions A, B, C, D and we need that whenever two individuals have B and C with positive values, they are more likely to be grouped together, and the same with A, D. Could this be managed by some transformation in the input data?

I would appreciate very much any ideas about how to deal with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you add a dummy variable, "kids"?

Comment: In other words, you want to override the *empirical* solution to the clustering with your *human judgment* about how the clusters should be formed? Why would you want to do this? It sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @CFD Is it not the same than the dimension "Number of children"?

Comment: @user332577 I understand it could look as a bad idea. However, what I'm trying to do is to give some extra real-world information to the clustering process. For example, I know that for my model, people with 0 kids are likely to be in a different group, so I'd like to tell this to the algorithm in some way. But I don't want to classify this people directly, because there could be more dimensions that bind a person with 0 kids to another person with kids, for example, geographical region.

Comment: When you think of hierarchical clustering you must think in terms of the distance (or similarity) matrix between your objects. Do not experiment with values blindly. Select a distance measure by its formula, consciously.

Comment: It sounds like you're interested in adding noncontinuous information to the clustering algorithm. Most hierarchical routines are old school and OLS based which means that they won't perform well when noncontinuous features are added, e.g., dummy variables. As an example, k-means with noncontinuous features such as dummies kind of *blows up* as the dummies end up driving the solution. To me, it sounds like you would be better off exploring one of the finite mixture model methods which are designed for data mixtures, e.g., latent class clustering. Lots of posts on CV re this.

Comment: @user332577   Thank you very much for your advice and hints

Comment: @ttnphns Thank you for your advice